# Avoid one frame delay in calculating child size

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have to create a reusable component that tries to achieve this goal: I have a column that can have content that's larger than the screen height. On the bottom of the screen we have panel with gradient background that can contain button or something else (it's basically a slot in the component). This bottom panel have to be always visible on the screen, and in case of the column being bigger than screen - bottom panel have to be on the top of this column. Gradient background does a nice UX effect so user knows what is going on. It looks like that:

[image]

I have that solved, but here's the challenge. The column content have to be scrollable to be on top of the bottom panel when scrolled to the end. Current solution I have is to add a spacer on the bottom of this column. This spacer have the calculated height of the bottom parent. And here's the issue - right now we have calculation done in `onSizeChanged` which basically results in additional frame needed for the spacer to have correct size.

We did not observe any negative impact of that performance or UX wise. The spacer height calculation never does anything that user can see, but I still want to solve that properly.

AFAIK this can be done using custom `Layout`, but that seems a little bit excessive for what I want to achieve. Is there another way to do this properly?

Current solution:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FloatingPanelColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentHorizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    bottomPanelContent: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    var contentSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(1)
    }
    Box(modifier) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                .then(contentModifier),
            horizontalAlignment = contentHorizontalAlignment,
        ) {
            content()
            val contentSizeInDp = with(LocalDensity.current) { contentSize.toDp() }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(contentSizeInDp))
        }

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onSizeChanged {
                    contentSize = it.height
                }
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color(0x00FAFCFF),
                            Color(0xFFF6F9FB),
                        )
                    )
                ),
            content = bottomPanelContent
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd use `LazyColumn`, you can specify `contentPadding` instead of `Spacer`. But to calculate size there's only two options: `onSizeChanged` as you're doing now, or `SubcomposeLayout`, using which you'll be able to use the bottom panel size directly.

Comment: I experimented with contentPadding, but effect is still the same. I'm still lagging this single frame. Do you have some pointers how to use `SubcomposeLayout` in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to depend on an other view size during layout is using `SubcomposeLayout`:

```kotlin
SubcomposeLayout { constraints ->
    // subcompose the view you need to measure first
    val bottomPanel = subcompose("bottomPanel") {
        Column(
            // ...
        )
    }[0].measure(constraints)
    // use calculated value in next views layout, like bottomPanel.height
    val mainList = subcompose("mainList") {
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = bottomPanel.height.toDp()) 
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }[0].measure(constraints)
    layout(mainList.width, mainList.height) {
        mainList.place(0, 0)
        bottomPanel.place(
            (mainList.width - bottomPanel.width) / 2,
            mainList.height - bottomPanel.height
        )
    }
}
```